# How to remove the first and the last character of a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm wondering how to remove the first and last character of a string in Javascript.

My url is showing `/installers/` and I just want `installers`.

Sometimes it will be `/installers/services/` and I just need `installers/services`.

So I can't just simply strip the slashes `/`.

Comment: I'm trying to just strip the first and last character of that. I'm just grabbing the URL

Comment: I just wonder why nobody seems to notice that trimming slashes (as the text indicates) and unconditionally removing the first and last char of a string (as the caption indicates) is not quite the same. But it explains the wide range of answers below.

Answer (score 501, accepted):

Here you go

```js
var yourString = "/installers/";
var result = yourString.substring(1, yourString.length-1);

console.log(result);
```

Or you can use `.slice` as suggested by [Ankit Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25567247/3063532)

```js
var yourString = "/installers/services/";

var result = yourString.slice(1,-1);

console.log(result);
```

Documentation for the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: But of the url doesnt end with a slash, it will take of 1 character

Comment: @Martijn this exactly answers the question. Nobody said you don't want strip anything other than slash ;). +1 from me - code should say what it's supposed to do, not like regex examples here.

Comment: But if you where to move to another server, the traling slash might not be there (or maybe you configed the change on purpose). Not downvoting, just pointing it out :)

Comment: The trailing slash is always going to be there because it's pointing to the index.php file...

Answer (score 179):

It may be nicer one to use `slice` like :

```
string.slice(1, -1)
```

Answer (score 23):

I don't think jQuery has anything to do with this. Anyway, try the following :

```
url = url.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
```

Comment: This looks like the most correct one so far. The only thing, I'd add a quantifier, just in case: `/^\/+|\/+$/g`.

Answer (score 12):

If you dont always have a starting or trailing slash, you could regex it. While regexes are slower then simple replaces/slices, it has a bit more room for logic:

```
"/installers/services/".replace(/^\/?|\/?$/g, "") 

# /installers/services/ -> installers/services
# /installers/services -> installers/services
# installers/services/ -> installers/services
```

The regex explained:

- ['start with' `^`] + [Optional`?`] + [slash]: `^/?`, escaped -> `^\/?`
- The pipe ( | ) can be read as `or`
- ['ends with' `$`] + [Optional `?`] + [slash] -> `/?$`, escaped -> `\/?$`

Combined it would be `^/?|/$` without escaping. Optional first slash OR optional last slash.
<sup>Technically it isn't "optional", but "zero or one times".</sup>

Comment: The thing is is that I can't strip the "/" because sometimes I'll need those to separate the inner parts of the url

Comment: The inner slashes dont go away. Ill edit and explain the regex

Comment: I think you need the global flag to make this work: "/installers/services/".replace(/^\/?|\/?$/g, "")

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like that :

```
"/installers/services/".replace(/^\/+/g,'').replace(/\/+$/g,'')
```

This regex is a common way to have the same behaviour of the `trim` function used in many languages.

A possible implementation of trim function is :

```
function trim(string, char){
    if(!char) char = ' '; //space by default
    char = char.replace(/([()[{*+.$^\\|?])/g, '\\$1'); //escape char parameter if needed for regex syntax.
    var regex_1 = new RegExp("^" + char + "+", "g");
    var regex_2 = new RegExp(char + "+$", "g");
    return string.replace(regex_1, '').replace(regex_2, '');
}
```

Which will delete all `/` at the beginning and the end of the string. It handles cases like `///installers/services///`

You can also simply do :

```
"/installers/".substring(1, string.length-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substring` method

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1) //removes last character
```

another alternative is `slice` method

Answer (score 3):

Use `string.slice(1, 0)` to remove **the first letter** of a string.

Use `string.slice(0, -1)` to remove **the last letter** of a string.

Comment: `s.slice(1,0)` does **not** remove the first letter, it removes the whole string. Use `s.slice(1)` for that.

Answer (score 2):

It is too nicer shortcode.

```
response.data.slice(1,-1) // "Prince"

-> Prince
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.replace(/.*\/(\S+)\//img,"$1")`

```
"/installers/services/".replace(/.*\/(\S+)\//img,"$1"); //--> services

"/services/".replace(/.*\/(\S+)\//img,"$1"); //--> services
```

Comment: This doesn't do what OP asked for.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```js
url=url.substring(1,url.length-1);
```

This way you can use the directories if it is like `.../.../.../...` etc.

Comment: `url.length` not `url.Length`