# How to HMAC-S256 encrypt a string in Node JS

Tags: php, node.js, hmac, cryptojs

I am pretty new to Node.

I am trying to get the following PHP code

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $canonicalString, $secret, true));
$signature = rtrim($signature,"=");
```

to work in node . Currently I have the following code implementation in node.

```
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key)
    .update(message)
    .digest('base64');
```

Still the service not getting authenticated.

Any help is much appreciated. Been stuck at the same line of code for more than a day.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like all you're missing is something to trim any `=` off the end.

Comment: I even tried the trim. still didn't work. After string is retuned Signature = Signature.substring(0, Signature.length - 1);. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Apart from trimming, there seems to be no functional difference. Base64 encoded strings can have no, one or two padding characters (`=`). Try trimming with `replace(/=+$/g,'')`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32516190). Authentication may also fail for another reason.

Comment: Show us example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late update. the following code worked for me.

```
return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key)
    .update(message)
    .digest('base64');
```

The mistake i did was using different keys in the PHP code and the node code.