# Regex to remove leading and trailing special characters and spaces from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a regex to remove all leading/trailing spaces as well as all leading/trailing special characters.

If I have the string:

```
test = '~!#@$@  hello this is a #! test  ^^#!^^    '
```

I'd like it to return as:

```
'hello this is a #! test'
```

So special characters and spaces in between the first and last letter are preserved, but all leading/trailing ones are cut out. Right now I have this:

```
test.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g,"").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
```

which returns:

```
'hello this is a  test'
```

so it is removing all special characters and leading/trailing spaces. How can I preserve that "#!" between "a" and "test"?

Comment: You can just use `.replace(/^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$/g,"")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156292/trim-specific-character-from-a-string

Answer (score 3):

By using the unicode flag `u` you can use the [Unicode Categories](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) for Letters `\p{L}` and Numbers `\p{N}` in a negative character class `[^...]`.
And match them at the start `^` or `|` at the end `$` to get anything that's not a letter or number and is trailing or leading.

**Pattern:**

```
^[^\p{L}\p{N}]+|[^\p{L}\p{N}]+$
```

**Test Snippet:**

```js
let test = '~!#@$@  hello this is a #! test  ^^#!^^    ';

test = test.replace(/^[^\p{L}\p{N}]+|[^\p{L}\p{N}]+$/gu, '');

document.write('['+test+']');
```

Comment: This does the trick, I appreciate the explanation of what everything means!

Comment: @bmorgs Nice. Just beware that the unicode categories were only introduced with ES2018. So some browsers might not be able to use them. The regex `/^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$/g` from Wiktor will work, but it'll only keep ascii letters and digits `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Not letters like ę ã ö