# Delete a character from the text

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to delete the first and last characters from the text with java script?

Can I just delete the letter ( X ) in each word at the beginning and end?
If the word starts or ends with a letter other than ( X ), I do not want to delete it

```html
<a id="Delete-first-and-last-letter" href="https://pice.com">XpiceX</a>
<a id="Delete-first-and-last-letter" href="https://min.com">XminX</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean the first and the last character?

Comment: Yes, the first and last character

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the first and the last character of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196088/how-to-remove-the-first-and-the-last-character-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
document.getElementById("Delete-first-and-last-letter").textContent =document.getElementById("Delete-first-and-last-letter").textContent.replace(/^X|X$/g, '');

document.getElementById("Delete-first-and-last-letter-1").textContent =document.getElementById("Delete-first-and-last-letter-1").textContent.replace(/^X|X$/g, '');

document.getElementById("Delete-first-and-last-letter-2").textContent =document.getElementById("Delete-first-and-last-letter-2").textContent.replace(/^X|X$/g, '');
```

```html
<a id="Delete-first-and-last-letter" href="https://pice.com">XpiceX</a>
<br/>
<a id="Delete-first-and-last-letter-1" href="https://pice.com">NoXpiceX</a>
<br/>
<a id="Delete-first-and-last-letter-2" href="https://pice.com">Xpice</a>
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine n but i discovered a new problem. 
She did delete letters in some words that I did not want to delete. 
Can I just delete the letter ( X ) in each word at the beginning and end?

Comment: تعمل ، ولكن تمنيت ان تعمل الشفرة على كلمات متعدد ، ما اقصد ان في الصفحة توجد اكثر من 10 كلمات تبدأ بي الحرف اكس كبير ولكن الشفرة تحدف فقط الكلمة الاولى وباقي الكلمات لا تعمل

Comment: When it is more than 2id with the same name it does not work in a second

Comment: The HTML spec required the ID attribute to be unique in a page

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the text from that element using `document.getElementById`, trim it accordingly using a `slice` function and replace the original text with the result:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('Delete_first_and_last_letter').text;

var b =a.slice(1, a.length - 1);

document.getElementById('Delete_first_and_last_letter').innerHTML= b;
```

```html
<a id="Delete_first_and_last_letter" href="https://pice.com">XpiceX</a>
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine n but i discovered a new problem. She did delete letters in some words that I did not want to delete. Can I just delete the letter ( X ) in each word at the beginning and end?

Comment: When it is more than 2id with the same name it does not work in a second

Comment: Vou used an ID in your question,  and you can't use an ID twice (the code you now have in your question is invalid HTML therefore). So that's what my answer was referring to. But you can as well use the `getElementsByClassName()` method and use a class for all elements which you want to be affected.