# matching regex pattern in javascript using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string from which I want to check if it only contains characters that are allowed. I want only characters of

- alphanumeric (lower & upper) : A-Z, a-z
- numeric (0-9)
- special characters: _&!.-
- space

example of valid strings:

- title1 - header
- title2&&& header_!.
- 09
- a912
- ...dd

example of invalid strings

- a$$$ ()
- a12345^&6**

if at least one of characters is not in the special characters so it not valid string. I would like to know how do test it in javascript.
the regex patterns come from server so it string.
I convert the regex pattern string by using RegExp but all of them show false, even some of them are valid.
the three first lines should be valid (**true**)

```js
 const pattern = "^[a-z0-9_&!.-\\s]+$";

                const strings = [
                  `title1 - header`,
                  `title2&&& header_!.-`,
                  `09`,
                  `a912 dd`,
                  `a$$$ ()`,
                  `a12345^&6**`
                ]
                const regex = new RegExp(pattern);

                strings.forEach(str => {

                  console.log(str, ' ---> ', regex.test(str));
                });
```

Comment: `"/^[a-z0-9_&!.-\s]+$/"` is not valid input for the RegExp constructor because you shouldn't be passing the `/` delimiters there. Either change your backend to give you valid regular expressions or pre-process this before feeding it into RegExp

Comment: how to improve it? to remove / delimiter?

Comment: [How to remove the first and the last character of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20196088)

Comment: no, I mean what do do that the regex pattern will work as expected? I'm the backend developer too, I sent it from server, so I can replace any value

Comment: Then don't send the `/` at the beginning and the end.

Comment: I edited the post and change it but still not valid

Comment: 1. You only changed the indentation 2. Your `pattern` variable is wrong here - `\s` has to be double escaped as `\\s`. But that's only an issue with the stack snippet. [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17863066)

Comment: check my edit post.. maybe my regex it not valid, if you think I need to change it ok, I wrote the rules in the post (A-Za-z0-9 ._&!.-)

Comment: You deleted the `-` which was part of your pattern

Comment: right, that's working. what is mean "\\s"? why I need it? and why I need "$"?

Comment: [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17863066) | [Matching exact string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/447250) | [What do ^ and $ mean in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6908725) | [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618)